# Product groups step doesn't show when setting up campaign

Tags: google-ads

"Product groups" and "Ad assets" steps display an empty page so I can't create new ads, is this a known issue? Any workarounds?

I tried different browsers, clearing the cache ad well as restarting the process multiple times.

[image]